# SPA content refresh with constant updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, service-worker

I know that recommended approach to updating SPA versions is to use service workers and alert user that he should refresh page. But what options do we have when there's lots of pages and new things constantly getting added? I believe this would annoy a lot of users especially when those updates aren't even related to the page they are using right now.

I was thinking about whenever new version exists refresh page when user goes to other page like clicking menu item. But it's far from perfect. Do I have other options?

Comment: I think you've confused the idea of a SPA with the idea of a PWA. You can update a SPA simply by invalidating the cache - this requires no effort on the users part. A PWA content update certainly requires user interaction. But, in that case, if there are parts of the app they don't use, those shouldn't be in the manifest anyway and should be lazy loaded as needed (hence the newest version would be retrieved upon lazy load).

Comment: Well yes no-cache for index works when user refresh the page. But why would he refresh it or open new page? This works for apps that aren't being constantly updated but it's companies intranet page and it will be updated all the time like 10, 50 or whatever times per day. We're currently using php+html so no issue since on every filter change on report page will be refreshed but with SPA even going through pages won't refresh it.

Comment: For example when I open quasar.dev and keep it open message will pop-up that I should refresh the page since new version exists. Now imagine employee working only with "report 1" and during the day I keep updating "Report 2". There's no reason for employee to refresh the page he can keep it open all day then after a while he clicks on "Report 2" and he sees old version since he didn't refreshed the page.

Comment: I know that vue won't magically know which components were updated and which weren't. So the only approach I can see is to do full refresh on every vue-router click. Just been wondering maybe there's a better option.

Comment: Wait so using service worker I can actually know when certain "report" or its components were updated? I don't like first option because it is possible that for example user will never need "report 2" but he will still see a popup about page refresh and if its updated 50 times a day it means that page willa sk for refresh every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this task - *"Show the alert to refresh the page when there is a new UI version available for the page being viewed by the user"*.

For that, you need to store **version** and **updated UI modules** for that version at the backend. e.g. lets say **Report-1, Report-5** were changed in a new version **1.2.3**.

Now, UI can send current UI version with each AJAX HTTP call (maybe in custom headers) and if the backend finds that UI is **stale**, it can respond with the **new version** and the list of **changed UI modules**: e.g. new version: **1.2.3** and changed UI modules: **Report-1, Report-5**.

Now UI can decide whether to show an alert or not by checking if the user is currently looking at one of the changed modules (which are Report-1 & Report-5 in this example).

So, for this example:

if the user is looking at Report-1, show the alert.

if the user is looking at Report-6, don't show the alert.