# How to purge browse cache - index.html stuck in cache

Tags: javascript, caching, cloudflare

I have a ReactJS app hosted in S3 and using Cloudflare as DNS & CDN.

I have a huge issue, a lot of visitors have old version of the application stored in their browser cache (index.html only). I have configured advanced cache control in the newest version, but it cannot be accessed because older version is shown instead.

Static file (CSS, JS) versioning is done using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build), but I have discovered that `index.html` file **is the only cached one**.

What should I do now? 
How to purge visitors cache now?

PS: I have purged Cloudflare cache already and setup rule to bypass cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such solution for this.

The only way is to wait until users cache will empty (expire).

> It is technicaly impossible to clear users cache from external resource (JS script etc.), due to security reasons.

Also if it will be possible, there is no way how to tell users to download latest JS (including cache purging code), because they have old version of index.html (including link to those .js files).

You are stack and the only option is to wait.

Comment: I agree! Either ask users to do it manually or wait until the browser decides (after cache expiry) to fetch the latest files from the server.

Comment: Though, as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358834/2873538); UI can try to *reload* the frontend files (HTML/CSS/JS) by checking for **App / Deployment** versions received in http rest API responses. @FilipNiko

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be, whenever your build changes, *change the JS link* so that the browser downloads the new version from the server, no matter the user's or the server's caching policy.

For example, the way Stack Exchange does it is, whenever the build changes, the HTML goes from something like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=1bac371ac78f"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=f83b2f654"></script>
```

Whenever there's a new build, you can randomize the parameter in the query string in the HTML, and still only have the single (most recent) built `.js` on your server.

Comment: I will check this option. Is there any option that this will solve my issue?
Because it seems like my issue is - old index.html is downloaded at first...

Comment: Are they really caching the *old* HTML, and not just other resources? That sounds quite odd, I thought HTML document requests were not cached.

Comment: Yes, I have appended app version inside index.html and I can see older version there. I will update the question.

Comment: Okay, I have just verified that this feature is already implemented natively by react-scripts which are used to build the app (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build).