# Cache busting in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack

How can I say to users that I have published a new update on my site, refresh the page in order to escape page crushing? Because every build generates new hashes(js, css). It can happen for example user visits my site, leaves the app open, I am publishing an update, user request some JS file(it's have already been cached), and page crushed because that file does not exist, or isn't consistent with another file. Technics I am using is custom react SSR rendering with webpack and express js.

Comment: See [SPA content refresh with constant updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66356321/2873538). Tell browser to not cache `index.html` files by sending a response header: `Cache-Control: no-store`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what to do if I i want to cache exist too(for performance). I have seen some websites, that shows some popup/alert and saying that new version available reload page(and in the background, they are cleaning cache), what is it?

Comment: I talked about "how / when to show alert when a new version of UI is available" in above linked post (ignore the modules part there). And, I think, in an SPA, you need to do [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to reload new version of SPA.